# Postgresql duplicate primary string key

Tags: postgresql

I'm facing a strange behaviour I have no explanation for.

I'm using:

```
PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

**Issue:**

I have a table like

```sql
create table symbols
(
    symbol varchar(20) not null
        constraint symbols_pkey
            primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null,
);
```

So symbols.symbol is actually a unique primary key.
But my program failed, when I tried to add a foreign key on that symbol. It told me, that the value 'c3' did not exists in that table.

I manually checked that by

```sql
SELECT * FROM symbols WHERE symbol = 'c3'
```

and it was really not present, but my code told me that it is!

After hours, I realized, that I can only find the symbol by

```sql
SELECT * FROM symbols WHERE symbol ilike 'c3'
```

Which returned:

```
symbol, name
c3,     c3
```

I was thinking that I made a mistake in sanatizing the input data, so I tried to create a new item by my IDE with a clean key.
But after that, I got two tuples:

```
symbol, name
c3,     c3
c3,     c3-new
```

And

```sql
SELECT * FROM symbols WHERE symbol = 'c3'
```

still did not return any tuples.

I checked if the collation is right and if the string lengths are correct.

```sql
select symbol,length(symbol),ascii(symbol) from symbols where symbol ilike 'c3';
```

tuples:

```
symbol, length, ascii
c3,     2,      99
c3,     2,      99
```

Than I created another item directly with Postgresql commands (no program code and no involved IDE), just plain SQL:

```sql
insert into symbols values('c3', 'c3-newest');
```

And now I got 3 tuples:

```
symbol, name
c3,     c3
c3,     c3-new
c3,     c3-newest
```

The primary key constraint was still not in effect here.
But when I tried to create a new item, I got:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "symbols_pkey" Detail: Key (symbol)=(c3) already exists.
```

**My questions:**

- What happened here? Where is the differences between these 3 'c3' strings and how I prevent that?
- I am missing some fundamental knowledge about varchar collations?
- Is there some Postgresql primary key error?

Answer (score 1):

I did a

```sql
REINDEX TABLE symbols
```

which fixed the problem!

I also switched from Docker image `postgresql:alpine` to `postgresql:13` because I heard that this could raise strange issues.

Comment: Probably has to do with the [system locale](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes)